# getElementById for a specific item in a row when there are multiple rows/ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a table that is populated via an ajax call, so it has n number of rows.

One of the columns in each row has a button which uploads documents.

Because the row is dynamic, the button has the same ID on every row. The problem is, I am trying to get the file for each row but can't do it as getElementById doesn't work (as there are multiple elements with the same ID because there are multiple rows) - it always just selects the top row.

If I do the following, I am able to get some information about the file, but not the file itself (as I can't work out how to get the actual HTML):

```
$('#TableName tbody').on('change', '#uploadFile', function () {
        var file = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[id='uploadFile']")
```

I can get the filename using file[0].value but I just can't get the actual HTML, and hence the file.

Is there any way to actually get the html and therefore the file using the same ID for every row? If not is there a way to use a different ID for each row or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. using javascript/jquery

Comment: `Because the row is dynamic, the button has the same ID on every row.`? ID should and **must** be unique in the page.

Comment: In HTML IDs must be unique, Use a common class then you can use class selector `.className`

Comment: Also, don't do `$('#TableName tbody')` but rather do `$('#TableName').find('tbody')`

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically create new IDs for each button on each row when the data is populated via ajax?

Comment: if the elements are created using script, then don't add an id... just use class... if you want to have a id... then use a counter variable

Comment: @Satpal if I use a classname instead, how do I go about identifying the unique button on the row that I want?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, every ID must be unique. You cannot use the same `id` on every row, that is invalid HTML.

Instead, use class; replace all `id` within your HTML with `class`, if before you had this:

```
<tr>
  <input id="uploadFile">
</tr>
```

you should replace it with:

```
<tr>
  <input class="uploadFile">
</tr>
```

and then you can match elements with that class by using this:

```
$('#TableName tbody').on('change', '.uploadFile', function () {
    var file = $(this).closest('tr').find("input.uploadFile]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I have followed it but calling  var file = $(this).closest('tr').find("input.uploadFile]") still does not return the actual HTML element I am after, it just brings back an object

Comment: @user3129594 it brings back a jQuery object. You can use this almost in exactly the same way as you would an element.

Answer (score 0):

Okay eventually got it working.

Changed it to class, got the current row index of the click, did a documents.getElementsByClassName and finally selected the row with that index.

Thanks for the help!